# How do I write a bash menu script so that the options are the contents of a list?

Tags: bash

I'm working with a generic bash menu script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Bash Menu Script Example

PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Option 1")
            echo "you chose choice 1"
            ;;
        "Option 2")
            echo "you chose choice 2"
            ;;
        "Option 3")
            echo "you chose choice 3"
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
    esac
done
```

When executed, reads like:

```
1) Option 1
2) Option 2
3) Option 3
4) Quit
Please enter your choice:
```

I have a file named list.txt:

```
Android
iOS
Windows
```

How do I write the bash menu script so that the options are the contents of list.txt:

```
1) Android
2) iOS
3) Windows
4) Quit
Please enter your choice:
```

Comment: `select opt in $(cat file) Quit; do :; done` The lines in the file should not contain spaces or tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace

```
options=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3" "Quit")
```

with

```
mapfile -t options < list.txt
options+=( "Quit" )
```

and adjust your `case` patterns. Instead of testing for the content of the `$opt` variable you could use `$REPLY` which contains the selected number and is easier to check.

Comment: So... I'm completely confused with how to adjust my case patterns.

Comment: Instead of `case $opt in` you can use `case $REPLY in` and instead of `"Option 1")` you can use `1)`.

Comment: Got it. So... Let's say that the list.txt file contains 100 lines. Is there a way around manually typing out the case patterns for `1)` -- `100)` ? Can there just be one line that satisfies `1) -- 100)` options?  I don't know if what I'm asking makes sense... sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The pattern `[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)` would match numbers 1-9, 10-99 and 100.

Comment: If all the options do the same thing, why do you need a menu? If they are distinct options, you need to write 100 action cases anyway. But you don't know in advance what is in the file, so you can't know what the numbers relate to. Maybe your file should contain a mapping for the keywords. Please ask another question that explains what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: How is the user going to scroll around a 100-line menu in a window?

Comment: I believe there is a scroll bar and it's located on the right hand side of most terminal windows. But no, you make very good points, Paul. And I appreciate your insight. Keyword mapping is a very good idea and I'll have to look into that. Now that you bring it up, it makes me wonder how metasploit framework is built...

Answer (score 0):

Read the file into an array:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readarray -t list < list.txt

PS3='Please enter your choice or 0 to exit: '
select selection in "${list[@]}"; do
    if [[ $REPLY == "0" ]]; then
        echo 'Goodbye' >&2
        exit
    else
       echo $REPLY $selection
        break
    fi
done
```